# Which level of data protection should I expect for a Linode personal server without backup service?

Tags: backup, vps, linode

all:

I bought a personal linode server without the backup service.

All the data on it is totally personal and not that important. But for sure, I still don't want them to be lost.

I want to know, without the backup service, which level of data protection should I expect?

Do they have in-place RAID or some other replication facilities for my data?

How do you think, without the backup service, the probability of a data loss would be?

Thanks.

Comment: **How do you think, without the backup service, the probability of a data loss would be?** - without backups? 100%, eventually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without backups, you have no data protection. RAID is for fault tolerance and availability in the event of a disk failure, not data protection. If you have a RAID 1 mirror and you accidentally delete or corrupt data, RAID isn't going to protect you.

Comment: thanks for your answer. in the mean time, just got some answer from irc channel that they're doing raid10. and I'll do some rsync to keep my data safe. As I said, those data is not that important and not that heavy used, so I guess that's fine for now.